# Is there a way to make the call stack maximum larger?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stack

I'm building a chemical reactor simulation API, and using node with numbers.js in the backend. Some of the calculations made for optimization require more crunching in stack size, but in some problems Javascript stack size is exceeded.

And is there a way to obtain information on the current stack size?

Comment: I guess you could implement a custom call stack manually.

Comment: You probably want to spread the load, rather than making it deeper. Unless each number depends on every other number, this is a thing you most likely want to solve using parallel processing instead of a deeper call stack.